# How do I print/echo dates in other languages in php

Tags: php, date

This is what I have right now. I want to print the date in the same format but in spanish, or any other language.

```
<?php echo date(" d F Y ",time());?>
//echoes 13 February 2016
```

I have looked through:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
echo strftime("%A");
```

but I can't understand how it works.

Comment: There are [great tutorials](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=php+date+tutorial) onilne.

Comment: Try setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish'); have given ans

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
echo strftime("%A");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");
echo strftime(" in Finnish is %A,");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime(" in French %A and");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
echo strftime(" in German %A.\n");
?>
```

and go through this link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to do [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).And if you want to get more language code, please visit this [website](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm).For More information about `strftime` click [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

> **setlocale** — Set locale information.
>
> **strftime** — Format a local time/date according to locale settings.

```
 <?php
   setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
   echo strftime("%A");
 ?>
```